# Maple: Generating a set of permutations.

Tags: permutations, maple

I want to create all permutations of the following expression.

$a_1 a_2 a_3 ..a_n a_n'.. a_3' a_2' a_1'$

Where a variable can only be swapped with it's prime partner.

Since there are n variables each with 2 possible positions I can see that there must be $2^n$ permutations.

I've not used Maple for 5 years so the more detailed the answer the better.

Ideally I would like the output to be a vector as I'm going to be creating a matrix by combining the output of this vector with another vector.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks, Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code fragment to help you get started:

```
P :=
proc(n)
local res, ind, d, perm;

    res := [];

    for ind from 2^n to 2*2^n-1 do
        d := convert(ind, base, 2)[1..n];

        perm :=
        [seq(`if`(d[p]=0,
                  a[p], b[p]), p=1..n),
         seq(`if`(d[n+1-p]=0,
                  b[n+1-p], a[n+1-p]), p=1..n)];

        res := [op(res), perm];
    od;

    res;
end;
```

Sample run is

```
> P(4);
[[a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], b[4], b[3], b[2], b[1]],

    [b[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], b[4], b[3], b[2], a[1]],

    [a[1], b[2], a[3], a[4], b[4], b[3], a[2], b[1]],

    [b[1], b[2], a[3], a[4], b[4], b[3], a[2], a[1]],

    [a[1], a[2], b[3], a[4], b[4], a[3], b[2], b[1]],

    [b[1], a[2], b[3], a[4], b[4], a[3], b[2], a[1]],

    [a[1], b[2], b[3], a[4], b[4], a[3], a[2], b[1]],

    [b[1], b[2], b[3], a[4], b[4], a[3], a[2], a[1]],

    [a[1], a[2], a[3], b[4], a[4], b[3], b[2], b[1]],

    [b[1], a[2], a[3], b[4], a[4], b[3], b[2], a[1]],

    [a[1], b[2], a[3], b[4], a[4], b[3], a[2], b[1]],

    [b[1], b[2], a[3], b[4], a[4], b[3], a[2], a[1]],

    [a[1], a[2], b[3], b[4], a[4], a[3], b[2], b[1]],

    [b[1], a[2], b[3], b[4], a[4], a[3], b[2], a[1]],

    [a[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], a[4], a[3], a[2], b[1]],

    [b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], a[4], a[3], a[2], a[1]]]
```

Comment: Thank you @Marko Riedel
If I wanted to insert elements into the middle of the vector is there a way to do this? All elements are numbers (base minus 1) e.g.

$a_1, \dots, a_n, b-1,b-1,\dots,b-1,b-1,a_n',\dots,a_1$

- motivation: I have a set of equations that govern every Kaprekar Routine fixed point in the form of a vector of expressions that go on the LHS and a vector of expressions that go on the RHS of an equation. I then solve each equation.

If you are interested in this at all and there is any way I could contact you directly I don't think the program requires too much more input

Comment: Thank your for the comment. I think it is in the spirit of MSE to motivate users to continue investigating on their own once a hint is provided. Seeing the code above it should not be difficult to determine how to use **seq** (Maple operator) or alternatively, **$**, to insert those extra constant values. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the extra hints! That has saved me several hours of googling!